# Building a table using material ui In react

Tags: reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I have a dynamic dataset for example:

```
a=[{name:'test',values['a','b','c']},{name:'test2',values['a1','b1','c1']}]
```

and I want to build a dynamic table, for this case:

```
test   test2
a        a1
b        b1
c        c1
```

using material UI,

```
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {a.map((header, index) => (
              <TableCell align="right" key={index}>{header.name}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {submissions.map((column, index) => {
            return a.inputData.map((row, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow key={index}>
                  <TableCell align="right">{row}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            });
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
```

but I can't seem to find a solution, this is the best I've gotten, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Tables are row based. So usually for every entry in your list you would have an additional row instead of an additional column. Also all values in a column should be of the same "type". Your column headers should be something like: name, a-value, b-value, c-value with each row having a value for those columns.

Comment: @trixn yes but i have this data set, Is there nothing I can do?

Comment: I don't see any point in rendering a table where no row shares values of the same "kind" that would appear in the same column. Does every dataset in your list have the same number of values? Do the values correspond to each other in any way?

Comment: @trixn the data set is dynamic , but there are allways the same number of values in any name, but there might be more names...

Comment: Well then your table should actually be flipped 90 degrees. I will provide you with an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description of the dataset this might be a possible solution:

```
<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      {a.map((column, index) => (
        <TableCell key={index}>{column.name}</TableCell>
      ))}
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {a[0].values.map((_, rowIndex) => (
      <TableRow key={rowIndex}>
        {a.map((row, colIndex) => (
          <TableCell key={colIndex}>
            {row.values[rowIndex]}
          </TableCell>
        ))}
      </TableRow>
    ))}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

[image: Edit elastic-butterfly-2cyp7]

Note that this requires every entry in your data set to have the exact same amount of values **and** there must be at least one entry in the list.

Basically it takes the number of expected values for each row from the length of the list of values of the first item in your data set. This seem very fishy to me and is very likely a flaw in your concept. Tables are row based and the number of rows should be the number of entries in your list.

Comment: Hi, this is not what I was asking about, I can't have fixed headers, the headers should be dynamic and must contain the name, and the rows beneath it should be the values...

Comment: @AlexK Then you just don't want a table. Tables are row-based by definition. I can't see any sense in having it the other way around. Don't the values rows have anything in common? Does the value `a` of your first column have the same type as the value `a` in of your second item?

Comment: Its not a question of sense, its the assignment I was required to do, they don't share anything in common except the location...

Comment: @Alex Then please provide an example of your dataset that actually shows the nature of the values instead of abstract a, b, c.

Comment: a,b,c represents strings, I just need to show them in that order.. that's it.

Comment: @AlexK I don't care about the data type, what kind of entity does each row or column represent? Is it a person or a product or what is it?

Comment: every header is an input , html input, the values are all the values that were inserted through that input, I need to show them as a table, for example: name is the header and the rows beneath it are : alex,tom,david, and the next header is last name, and the values are : chandler,fernendez,cohen, something like that.

Comment: @AlexK So that means a first name and a last name that are in the same row have actually nothing to do with each other, they just happen to be in the same row of that "table"? It's just that I can't see why you would want a table for that as that is not a table. It's more like some lists next to each other. And that is also the reason why it's so hard to render it correctly. It doesn't fit the concept of a table.

Comment: @AlexK Well okay so not questioning your reasoning behind why you would want a table for that I edited my answer. See if this works for you.

Comment: thanks it works, although some syntax errors, but I fixed it

Comment: @AlexK I updated my answer with a corrected version and a live example. Please check if that is correct and works for you.